# ClearDB - Can't create a TRIGGER from within another stored routine

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy tratando de crear un trigger con un ClearDB que tengo de Heroku, hasta donde entiendo ClearDb es `MySQL`, he trabajado bien con él hasta ahora que quiero hacer un triiger insert after insert, estoy usando `SQLPro` como interfáz.

Este es mi query

```
    CREATE TRIGGER usercount
AFTER INSERT
   ON users_ FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

   DECLARE vUser varchar(50);

   -- Find username of person performing the INSERT into table
   SELECT USER() INTO Users_;

   -- Insert record into audit table
   INSERT INTO userscount_
   ( contact_id)
   VALUES
   ( NEW.id_user
    );

END;
```

Y esto lo que me devuelve

> MySQL said: Can't create a TRIGGER from within another stored routine

Comment: debes hacer un `DROP TRIGGER usercount;` y luego volverlo a crear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]creo que estas intentado insertar este query dentro del campo "Definición", prueba de poner solo esto:

```
   BEGIN

   DECLARE vUser varchar(50);

   -- Find username of person performing the INSERT into table
   SELECT USER() INTO vUser;

   -- Insert record into audit table
   INSERT INTO userscount_
   ( contact_id)
   VALUES
   ( NEW.id_user
    );

END;
```

ademas he cambiado Users_ por vUser.

Comment: me da esto 
MySQL said: You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

Comment: Edita los privilegios del usuario con el que estas creando el TRIGGER, o inicia sesión con un usuario con mas privilegios

Comment: cómo puedo cambiar los privilegios de mi user?